# Need to run getAuthToken twice before receiving access token, why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I think I need to take some aspirin... banging my head to the wall... 3 days and still getting nowhere... I just don't get it...

From a Chrome extension I'm calling getAuthToken from background.js, it is probably the most basic script ever written:

```
function getAuthToken(){            
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken(   
        {'interactive': true},
            function(token){                            
                console.log(token);         
            } 
        );     
};
```

**Manifest snippet:**

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src https://*.google.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<client_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"]
  }
```

This is what happens:

1. Load the extension
2. OAuth2 is started, access to GMail is asked (pop-up) and granted
3. Console log: token = undefined and Unchecked runtime.lastError while
   running identity.getAuthToken: Authorization page could not be
   loaded (lastError 133)
4. In Chrome tokencache I see a new, but not present token (no token string)
5. Reload the extension
6. No Gmail access is asked
7. Token is now correctly received

Why do I need to run getAuthToken twice? I use step 2 authentication for GMail but understood this only applies to the front end.

Please if you ran into something similar share it with me, it is so frustrating not getting any further than 5 lines of code.

Comment: how are you calling getAuthToken() in background?

Comment: It is called on jquery $(document).ready function in background.js but I also tried to call it immediately, same result. To test I disabled step 2 verification but the problem remains. Once an empty or expired token is in the tokenCache it works fine, it only appears when I have to grand access to GMail. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Okay, I also tried this example https://github.com/GoogleDeveloperExperts/chrome-extension-google-apis and also here it fails the first load, after a second load it gets the token. Can it be because the extension is not yet published but runs locally?

Comment: I tried the whole thing on another computer which is on another network and the issue does not present itself. First call, token received. The problem happens on Server 2012R2, the working one is a  Windows 7. Obvisouly I tried disabling firewalls (Sophos UTM) and virus scanner (ESET), no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure if it is necessary, but worth trying to add the google urls to the permissions request in your manifest (then reload extension afterward to ensure it takes effect):     `"https://www.googleapis.com/", "https://accounts.google.com/", "https://*.googleusercontent.com/"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of your other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688191/getauthtoken-authorization-page-could-not-be-loaded-error-after-removing-token

Comment: Hi Steve, alas adding the permission like suggested did not resolve the issue. Thanks for your feedback. I tried on a third PC within the same network as Server 2012R2 and it work correctly, could it be OS related? Same versions of Chrome (43.0.2357.124 m)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am seeing the same issue. Also for about 10% of users, it never works...

Comment: @GeorgeB Have you found a solution for this? I have a same problem...

Comment: @kecman I spent an entire day with no luck. Very frustrating and there is no error message with any useful info. I ended up having to link to my webserver, have the user go through the normal oAuth flow, then copy/paste their refresh token into the extension.... then manage refreshing it myself. Total PITA. I had one of the bad users create a  new email address and everything worked.... so it has to be something account specific - but I couldn't find a common thread. I highly suspect this is a bug on google's end. Please let me know if you figure out a solution